# Where do I begin coding these sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

What language do I use? I have very little knowledge of Java Script so I doubt I'll be able to code them alone.

What would at least be the basis code to start with?

[These are the sliders](http://i43.tinypic.com/2mhxuf9.png) - they're just Photoshop images right now...

Comment: suggestion: google jQuery ui slider. Then hire a programmer.

Comment: Start acquiring some Javascript knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JQuery slider UI library](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider). You should be able to make some tweaks to get it doing what you want to.